# I have trouble every bundle install with my rails. How to fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, bundle

With guide on gorails I set up homebrew, rbenv and rails. But then when I work with other project from github and when I do bundle install It doesn't work.

Here is the error, I am looking for the answer but still don't find

```
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.4/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Thanks

Comment: do "which ruby" and "which rails" and paste the output in the question

Comment: /Users/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby, /Users/user/.rbenv/shims/rails @Mircea

Comment: did you rehash after installing the rails gem?

Comment: yes, I solved it by hard reinstalling all environment dependencies @Mircea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a rehash failure, run: `rbenv rehash`

If that works, [see here for why.](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#understanding-shims)